# Excel Conditional formatting Dates older then 60 days

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to use one Conditional formatting rule that does the following:

1. Ignore Blank Cells
2. Ignore Cells that do not have a date value
3. Highlight Dates that are going to expire in 30 days

So i have a list of dates:
07/25/2021
06/25/2021
05/25/2021
etc...

i used the custom formula under conditional formatting and used the following codes:

```
=CountIF(A:Z,today()-30)
```

i also used

```
=CountIF(A:Z,"<="&today()-30)
```

both codes highlight blank cells, i tried using the IF statements or IsBlank statements but i don't think i fully understand how those work. because i made a mess.

regardless of what i do, cells that are non-dates and blank cells are highlighted.

i even tried using the the conditional formatting rule, "Format only cells that contain" and i added the following:

Format Only cells with:
Cell value - less than or equal to - Today()-30

what do you guys think im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your dates are in column B:

1. Select entire column B.
2. From menu start `Format / Conditional formatting...`
3. Add a new rule with the plus sign.
4. At `Style` select `Classic`.
5. After select `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`
6. Enter this expression: `=AND($B1<>"",$B1<=TODAY()-30)`
7. Select a desired formatting.

You can easily adjust this to row or any other range, or +30 days etc.

If you need more columns, select all of them, and assuming that the first column is `A`, the formula should be: `=AND(A1<>"",A1<=TODAY()-30)`. See the screenshot below with formula and some example data:

[image: Example data and formula]

Comment: so i am trying to cover the entire Spreadsheet, so any date values are identified. once identified and evaluated, i want to highlight dates that are 30 days old or expiring in 30days. i never considered using "AND" in my formula! 

regarding your method, i tried it and it didn't work, also i couldn't find the style area to select classic.

Comment: But you could find where to enter a formula for conditional formatting?

Comment: Anyway, you can use a very similar formula, it works (I tried it). You select all the columns that you want to formal, and assuming, that the first column is A, the formula is: `=AND(A1<>"",A1<=TODAY()-30)`.

Comment: @JeffreyRodriguez I changed my answer and added a screenshot, hope it helps.

Comment: IT WORKED!! i needed to highlight columns, that was my issue. i apologize!