# Conditional format of days since compared to TODAY

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to use this in excel but I am woefully unequipped. I did some google-fu but I am a student and not a master so please forgive me if this info is easily obtained and I just didn't find it:

if([date in cell] >= 90 days since TODAY) shade cell red

if(no date in cell) shade cell yellow

if([date in cell] <= 90 days since TODAY) shade cell green

I tried the first if statement in the conditional formatting and the logic looks like this:
="TODAY()-90"

I tried the solution here:
[Excel Conditional formatting Dates older then 60 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68558585/excel-conditional-formatting-dates-older-then-60-days)

But I only have the cloud version of excel and I don't have the ability to "Use a formula to determine..." or I just don't see it.

In my conditional formatting I've even tried just highlighting today with:
Cell Value >="TODAY()" and it doesn't change shading.

Comment: First of all, I’d get rid of the double quotes.  Very often by default excel places double quotes around a formula entered in a dialog box.  You have to go back in after clicking OK and delete the double quotes.   You want a formula like `G6>=TODAY()-90` with no double quotes.